# Building a list of enum flags

Tags: c#, winforms, enum-flags

I have this method that accepts multiple `JobSetting` flags

```
private void ProcessTheData(string[] dataFiles, PictureBox sender, JobSetting? jobSetting)
```

The Flags enum is this

```
[Flags]
enum JobSetting
{
    ForcePrint = 1,
    ForceProof = 2,
    UseDefault = 4,
    SkipImposition = 8,
    HighPriority = 16,
    SetDP = 32
}
```

I have a event handler that looks at a CheckboxList and I build a list of flags based on the options that are checked.

```
JobSetting js;
if (((Control)sender).Name.ToLower().Contains("proof"))
{
    if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("Skip Imposition") && chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("High Priority") && chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("_SetDP"))
    {
        js = (JobSetting.ForceProof | JobSetting.SkipImposition | JobSetting.HighPriority | JobSetting.SetDP);
    }
    else if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("Skip Imposition") && chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("High Priority"))
    {
        js = (JobSetting.ForceProof | JobSetting.SkipImposition | JobSetting.HighPriority);
    }
    else if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("Skip Imposition"))
    {
        js = (JobSetting.ForceProof | JobSetting.SkipImposition);
    }
    else if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("High Priority"))
    {
        js = (JobSetting.ForceProof | JobSetting.HighPriority);
    }
    else if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("_SetDP"))
    {
        js = (JobSetting.ForceProof | JobSetting.SetDP);
    }
    else
    {
        js = JobSetting.ForceProof;
    }
}
```

It all works... but I feel like that has to be least effective way to build my list of flags.

I would like to build it in this fashion, or whatever correct way already exists to do it.

```
JobSeetings js = JobSetting.ForceProof;
if(chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("Skip Imposition"))
{
    js.add(JobSetting.SkipImposition)
}
if(chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("High Priority"))
{
    js.add(JobSetting.HighPriority)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just combine the flags with bitwise OR based on the items that are checked.

```csharp
JobSetting js = JobSetting.ForceProof;
if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("Skip Imposition"))
{
   js |= JobSetting.SkipImposition;
}
if (chkbxList_Proof.CheckedItems.Contains("High Priority"))
{
   js |= JobSetting.HighPriority;
}
//etc, etc...
```

If `"Skip Imposition"` and `"High Priority"` are checked, then `js` will be equal to `JobSetting.ForceProof | JobSetting.SkipImposition | JobSetting.HighPriority`.

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua!